# German site is not indexed, Search Console says it is duplicate of the English site, even though it is different language content

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url, multiple-domains, multilingual

I have problems to understand why my website isn't ranked correctly. I have 2 domains which open the site in 2 different languages:

DE: https://ausgaben-rechner.de/
EN: https://expense-calculator.com/

The EN domain gets ranked correctly, but the DE domain doesn't get indexed.

In Google Search Console they say:

> Duplicate - not user-defined as canonical

But how is this possible? It's total different content. The one is in English, the other in German. What exactly is wrong with my tags? I setted already the `hreflang` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your German site isn't 100% translated.  It has an English footer, site notice, and privacy policy.   If all of those were translated, I would bet that Googlebot wouldn't see your site as duplicate anymore.

Your home page has 13 words that are translated and 20 words that are not. Given that ratio, you might understand how Google wouldn't see your German site as German enough not to be duplicate.

I realize that your prominent and useful content is translated, but Googlebot doesn't always correctly identify the most useful parts of the page and it sometimes weights the boilerplate too much.

Comment: Oh thank you for the fast and usefull reply! I got a short seo text.. But its bad for UX to display it. So can i place it in a pre-rendered dialog box? its in the html code available, but invisible before clicking on a button. Or is this bad for SEO?

Comment: If you don't display it in the page without a click it is unlikely to change your SEO.  It shouldn't hurt, but it won't help either.   Rather than focus on that, I would recommend getting all the English words on the page translated.

Comment: All text things are translated now. Search console error `Duplicate - not user-defined as canonical` is gone now. Letz wait and hope that it get correctly indexed now. Any improovement ideas?

Comment: That was faster for Google to resolve the error after you made changes than I expected.

Comment: Thanks it worked. allready new indexed. now in 2 languages available on google :)

Answer (score 0):

Your German page is also saying the language is English:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Comment: Probably not a factor because Google doesn't even use that.  [Google Ignores The HTML lang Attribute](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-ignores-the-html-lang-attribute-22974.html)

Comment: but strange, because i got <html lang="de"> on the german one.

Answer (score -1):

Add a self referring canonical to each version.

on the .de page above the hreflang in the  add:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://ausgaben-rechner.de/" />
```

on the .com page above the hreflang in the  add:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://expense-calculator.com/" />
```

Google does see 2 language versions but doesnt know which one is the original so it auto-picks one. You have to declare that both versions are originals and have alternative version.

Comment: Thanks alot! i will try that later and request a reIndexing.

Comment: Make sure all your pages have a self-referring canonical. To re-index your page just re-submit the sitemap.

Comment: If Google thinks the pages are duplicate, canonical tags won't help.  Google just ignores canonical tags when it thinks they are wrong.  Not that putting the canonical tags on is wrong or will hurt in any way, I just don't expect it to solve this problem.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Google thinks the pages are duplicate because there is no canonical link in the first place if user doesn't declare a original version Google will do. You might be right but i had the same case with one of my clients.